# Debugging Cloud Endpoints: Error making request, but no request appears in logs

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an issue with debugging and Cloud Endpoints. I'm using tons of endpoints in my application, and one endpoint consistently returns with error code 500, message "Internal Error".

This endpoint does not appear in my app's logs, and when I run its code directly in the interactive console (in production), everything works fine.

There might be a bug in my code that I am failing to see, however, the real problem here is that the failing endpoints request is NOT showing up in my app's logs – which leaves me with no great way to debug the problem.

Any tips? Is it possible to force some kind of "debug" mode where more information (such as a stack trace) is conveyed back to me in the 500 response from endpoints? Why isn't the failing request showing up in my app's logs?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you aren't aware - by default the Logs webpage does not show you the lowest level log statements.  That missing level ('D', I think) adds lots of Endpoints log statements that occur prior to the invocation of your code, so they could be useful in the situation you describe.

I also find it useful to retrieve my log statements with 'appcfg' (in the GAE SDK), e.g.

```
appcfg --num_days=1 --severity=0 request_logs myfile.log
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about downloading the logs. The logs I can download using `appcfg` are identical to the ones I can view in the admin console. However, the failing endpoints request simply does not appear in the logs at all – even though it returns to the client with a 500 response.

All my other requests show up in the logs (including other requests that fail), this one simply doesn't appear at all. :(

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are running out of resources.

Comment: That's not what's happening as other requests appear just fine in the logs. (Including ones that error.)